# App crashes with OnClickListener in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app with 3 tabs and one of them has a todo-function. Everything works fine when I want to add a new note. Now I wanted to implement a delete function for the notes and since I can't access the button from the .xml file I tried it with `public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener` and `public void onClick(View v)` but now my App crashes completly when I start it. What do I do wrong?
Here the Fragment:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton btn_ok;
EditText edit_task;
private TaskDbHelper mHelper;
public ListView mTaskListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mHelper = new TaskDbHelper(getActivity());
    mTaskListView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_todo);
    updateUI();

    Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

public void updateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE, new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE},
            null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.item_todo, R.id.task_title, taskList);
        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_task, null);
            btn_ok = mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok5);
            edit_task = mView.findViewById(R.id.edit_task);
            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();

            btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String task = String.valueOf(edit_task.getText());
                    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                    db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                    db.close();

                    updateUI();

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_delete:
            View parent = (View) v.getParent();
            TextView taskTextView = parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
            String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?", new String[]{task});
            db.close();

            updateUI();

            break;
    }
} }
```

Logcat:

```
    12-06 19:35:58.710 20306-20306/com.example.rike1.final_logbuch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.rike1.final_logbuch, PID: 20306
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.example.rike1.final_logbuch.Tab2.onCreateView(Tab2.java:49)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1485)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:775)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1485)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:775)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:729)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2436)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1482)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1741)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6768)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:926)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
12-06 19:35:58.710 20306-20306/com.example.rike1.final_logbuch E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:912)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

XML item_todo where the Button is I want to access:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Done"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

tab2 XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_todo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This would be easier with a stacktrace

Comment: Take a look at this link (the information in the Logcat can be copied and pasted in your question) :: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Post your XML, is that ID present?

Comment: I added the Logcat and the XML where the button is

Comment: Just to be sure, the xml file you posted is called "tab2.xml" and is located in res/layout folder, right?

Comment: @colens Ahh ok, no tab2 contains a ListView and the button is in the XML for the notes i add into the ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the item click listener in ListView and use that. You can't just find the ListViews items because there would be multiple of them.

```
mTaskListView.setOnItemClickListener(this); // And remember to implement the interface
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Then you can move your code from method `onClick` to `onItemClick`

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView taskTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // and so on...
}
```

and ofcourse you need to remove the lines which are causing the null pointer exception:

```
Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: "And remember to implement the interface" do you mean this `public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` Sorry to ask again, the app isn't crashing anymore, but the button dosn't work

Comment: Yeah that. How does it not work? Can you debug and say that it's still executing that onItemClick-method?

Comment: Ah ok, so you need to extend that ArrayAdapter class and create your own adapter class. In there you infalte the list item in getView and set the "delete button" listener in there.

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating tab2.xml like this

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
```

But you can't get your button from it

```
Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
```

since the view you inflated doesn't contain **btn_delete**. That is why you are getting Null exception from the above line.